# Julia type instability: Array of LinearInterpolations

Tags: performance, julia

I am trying to improve the performance of my code by removing any sources of type instability.

For example, I have several instances of `Array{Any}` declarations, which I know generally destroy performance. Here is a minimal example (greatly simplified compared to my code) of a 2D Array of `LinearInterpolation` objects, i.e

```
n,m=5,5
abstract_arr=Array{Any}(undef,n+1,m+1)
arr_x=LinRange(1,10,100)

for l in 1:n
    for alpha in 1:m
        abstract_arr[l,alpha]=LinearInterpolation(arr_x,alpha.*arr_x.^n)
    end
end
```

so that `typeof(abstract_arr)` gives `Array{Any,2}`.

**How can I initialize `abstract_arr` to avoid using `Array{Any}` here?**

And how can I do this in general for Arrays whose entries are structures like Dicts() where the Dicts() are dictionaries of 2-tuples of Float64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main trick is that you just need to know the type of the object that is returned by `LinearInterpolation`, and then you can specify that instead of `Any` when constructing the array. To determine that, let's look at the `typeof` one of these objects

```
julia> typeof(LinearInterpolation(arr_x,arr_x.^2))
Interpolations.Extrapolation{Float64, 1, ScaledInterpolation{Float64, 1, Interpolations.BSplineInterpolation{Float64, 1, Vector{Float64}, BSpline{Linear{Throw{OnGrid}}}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, BSpline{Linear{Throw{OnGrid}}}, Tuple{LinRange{Float64}}}, BSpline{Linear{Throw{OnGrid}}}, Throw{Nothing}}
```

This gives a fairly complicated type, but we don't necessarily need to use the whole thing (though in some cases it might be more efficient to). So for instance, we can say

```
using Interpolations
n,m=5,5
abstract_arr=Array{Interpolations.Extrapolation}(undef,n+1,m+1)
arr_x=LinRange(1,10,100)

for l in 1:n
    for alpha in 1:m
        abstract_arr[l,alpha]=LinearInterpolation(arr_x,alpha.*arr_x.^n)
    end
end
```

which gives us a result of type

```
julia> typeof(abstract_arr)
Matrix{Interpolations.Extrapolation} (alias for Array{Interpolations.Extrapolation, 2})
```

Since the return type of this LinearInterpolation does not seem to be of known size, and

```
julia> isbitstype(typeof(LinearInterpolation(arr_x,arr_x.^2)))
false
```

each assignment to this array will still trigger allocations, and consequently there actually may not be much or any performance gain from the added type stability when it comes to *filling* the array. Nonetheless, there may still be performance gains down the line when it comes to using values stored in this array (depending on what is subsequently done with them).

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 3):

If you make a comprehension, the type will be figured out for you:

```
arr = [LinearInterpolation(arr_x, ;alpha.*arr_x.^n) for l in 1:n, alpha in 1:m]

isconcretetype(eltype(arr)) # true
```

When it can predict the type & length, it will make the right array the first time. When it cannot, it will widen or extend it as necessary. So probably some of these will be `Vector{Int}`, and some `Vector{Union{Nothing, Int}}`:

```
[rand()>0.8 ? nothing : 0 for i in 1:3]
[rand()>0.8 ? nothing : 0 for i in 1:3]
[rand()>0.8 ? nothing : 0 for i in 1:10]
```